# For which functions $h(x)$ does $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{h(f(x))}{h(g(x))}$ hold?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be continuous functions.

For which functions $h(x)$, does $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{h(f(x))}{h(g(x))}$$ hold, assuming that the limit exists?

I'm not sure whether a positive solution exists, I'm merely curious whether anyone knows any relevant results, perhaps also with different or stronger conditions on $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

Comment: Assuming both limits exist, then the most general condition I can think of is that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{h(f(x))}{f(x)}\frac{g(x)}{h(g(x))} = 1$$

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I'm wondering whether one can find a condition on $h(x)$ which is independent of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

Comment: We can't without more information about $f$ and $g$. Do $f,g\to\infty$ or to $a,b\in\Bbb{R}$. It's physically impossible without knowing at least that information. If the former, then the condition would boil down to $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{h(x)}{x}=1$$